# How to push n arguments to stack without assembler

Tags: c, stack, variadic

I'm writing a wrapper for calling a function with a different number of arguments,
i need to make **push arguments without assembler** how i can make it?

lazy code example:

```
typedef void (*call_func_t)();
 
for (int i = 0; i < argsCount, ++i) 
{
    push(args[i]); 
}
 
call_func_t f = fPtr;
f();
```

Comment: No idea whst you mean. Please elaborate according to [ask].

Comment: You've got what I call the "inverse varargs problem".  You want libffi.

Comment: You can't just place "an argument" on the stack. You need to know what they are, the order, and if they should even be placed on the stack. libffi handles all that for you.

Comment: i am writing an interpreter and i need to call a C function

Comment: Push argsCount and ensure that all parameters above have 'size' metadata?

Comment: @Limaaron Don't let these other doubters discourage you.  It's an interesting problem.  I've written an interpreter, too.  At first I used assembler (learned a lot, but an unmaintainable mess), and then later I switched to libffi.

Comment: unfortunately i can't use external libs

Comment: If someone expects you to do this without external libraries *and* without using any assembler, they are a very cruel, sadistic person!  I'm honestly not sure what kind of assignment you've been given, or what someone realistically expects you to do.  This problem -- calling a function with an argument list constructed at run-time -- is at the top of my list of things that simply cannot be done in C.

Comment: The only way to do this portably is to have a fixed, limited number of argument lists you know how to call with (like: (1) one int; (2) two ints; (3) one int and one pointer; (4) one int, two pointers, and one double; (5) one int and one long int; etc.), and use a `switch` statement or `if`/`else` chain to call them explicitly.

Comment: I tried to reserve an array on the stack, but I do not know how to pass it as an argument list.
`int arrBuf[512]; int* sPtr = &arrBuf`

Comment: I know of three ways to do this: (1) Use assembler. (2) Use an external library, like libffi. (3) Limit yourself to a fixed, known-in-advance set of argument lists.  But there is no way in straight C to say, "push an argument on the stack, just like it was about to be used in a function call."  There is no way in straight C to say, "Call this function pointer, using arguments I already pushed on the stack somehow."  In straight C, the only way -- the *only* way -- to push arguments on the stack is to list them in source code between the `(` `)` of an actual functional call.