# Is it possible to call a function (from a function pointer) with dynamic signature?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

In C, From [What is guaranteed about the size of a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer) it's seems like generic generic function pointers are possible.

Suppose you store the function signature along with the pointer (in a way or another... for example : the size of each parameters), Is it possible to call dynamically this function ? (the signature is only known at runtime).
The return type is void for all the function, and only the parameter list changes

I was wondering if casting to a varargs function would do the trick ?

(Bonus) The question is for C, but in C++, is it possible to use a similar techniques, and to apply it on instance methods ?

(I don't expect necessarily standard-compliant solution, but still something that is supported enough by most compilers)

Comment: Don't ask for both C and C++ in a single question

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, I'll edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there such a thing as a generic function pointer in C that can be assigned/cast to a more restrictive prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482624/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-generic-function-pointer-in-c-that-can-be-assigned-ca)

Comment: Can you give us some examples of functions? Do they have the same return type? Are only the argument list different?

Comment: Oh forgot about the return type...
it's void, I precise. Only the arg list is different

Comment: @mch no, the question is about actually making the call (from a `void (*)(void)` pointer)

Comment: "store the function signature along with the pointer" You cannot (as far as the standard goes). "in a way or another... for example : the size of each parameters" This is not enough. Nothing is enough. You cannot store a signature as data and then interpret that data to make an actual call.

Comment: As for non-standard-compliant solutions, try [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: See [C late binding with unknown arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868).  See also [How to push n arguments to stack without assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184297).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int a)
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

void bar(char* a, double b)
{
    printf("bar\n");
}

void baz(void)
{
    printf("baz\n");
}

int main()
{
    void (*arr[])() = {foo, bar, baz};

    arr[0](1, 1, 2);
    arr[1]("test", 2.0);
    arr[2]();
}
```

An empty parameter list in a function pointer means unspecified number of parameters. But you have to remember the parameters, when you call a function. Additional parameters are ignored (see `arr[0](1, 1, 2);`). Too few parameters is a problem.

Comment: This won't work reliably.  `void (*arr[])()` is an array of pointers to functions that take an indeterminate number of arguments.  The arguments to functions like that undergo [default argument promotions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6), which functions such as `void foo(int a)` **do not expect**.  This may **appear** to work, but it's wrong.