# Dynamically call C library functions with varargs

Tags: c, language-design

I'm currently writing my own programming language with similar goals to C. My compilation target is LLVM.

The next item on my list is compile time code execution. In order for that to be useful I need to be able to call builtin functions. I'm auto-generating function prototypes from the C standard library in order to be able to call them from my language. Now, in order to call those functions when interpreting the CALL instruction, I had the idea of wrapping the function prototypes with a more generic function that accepts a `void*` for the arguments and the result.
In my language that wrapper looks something like this:

```
export import def #extern gethostname(__name: *char, __len: ulong) -> int
def _Fgethostname(args: [*], ret: *) {
    @(ret !*int) = gethostname(@(args[0] !**char), @(args[1] !*ulong))
}
```

The idea is that I can store the function pointer in an array together with the function name in order to be able to pick the correct function at compile time.

Translated to C the wrapper would be this:

```
int gethostname(__name: *char, __len: unsigned long)
void _Fgethostname(void **args, void *ret) {
    *((int*)ret) = gethostname(*((char**)args[0]), *((unsigned long*)args[1]))
}
```

As long as a lay out the memory correctly, this should work.
Sadly my approach doesn't work for variadic functions.

I know that Python can call C functions, even with variadic arguments. What am I missing?

Comment: What you're probably missing is that it uses implementation-specific knowledge to lay out the arguments properly.

Comment: I believe the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184297), are the best you can do in C — in particular, using [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).  If I've misunderstood your question, I apologize, and I will support reopening.