# How to declare a function if it's return value and parameters are given in command line and unknown before implementation?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-interface

I have the following command line arguments: dlibrary name, name of the function, signature, function's parameters (if necessary).
Signature is a string, which consists of first letters of types.
First letter is a return value.
For example, viid is `void (int, int, double)`
I want to call this function with given parameters

For example, if I have to find sin(0.5)

```
./func libm.so.6 sin dd 0.5
```

I can't come up with idea how to define such function in C.

I thought if it is possible to change typedef in C but couldn't find anything about it. Help me, please. I don't even know where to read about this "redefinition". There is no information in Kernighan-Ritchi.

Comment: Are you trying to declare this function, or define it, or call it?

Comment: And what exactly it is supposed to do? Do you have an example?

Comment: It is a function from a given dlibrary. I know the library's name, the function's name and can find it with `dlopen` and `dlsym`

Comment: I can get a function sin, for example. It will have signature 'dd'

Comment: To find the function it is sufficient to know it's name. Sounds like you also want to invoke it with some parameters?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: So sounds like your invocation should be `./program func_name param1 param2 ....` and not what you said

Comment: You won't be able to do so. The returned pointer will need to be explicitly or implicitly cast to the type of the pointer to the function so that it can be used to call

Comment: For example, to call sin you need to do this `typedef double (*func_t) (double);`

Comment: I am not saying *how* to do it, I am saying that your question is an XY-problem, while the right X-problem description should be as I said.

Comment: `func_t f = "function, that we have found";`

Comment: If you add the types explicitly as you propose `./func name ret_type type1 type2  param1 param2`  you *could* achieve this but not using pure C, but making use of your knowledge of the specific ABI calling convention. That is parse the parameters according to the types, then push them into registers/stack according to ABI and call the function using assembly.

Comment: You are trying to solve what I call the "inverse varargs problem": trying to call an arbitrary function whose arguments aren't known until run time.  It's a fun problem, but you cannot solve it in portable C, at all; it's perfectly impossible.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868) for some hints and nonportable answers, and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184297).

Comment: Or make a program, that will generate another full C program text declaring and loading this function from the library, and then invoking a compiler on it and running the result.

Comment: Short answer: You want [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll think on it.